# How to render all the contents of a view in a custom module?

Tags: views, 7, theming

I have created a view with 4 blocks. Rose,lilly,sunflower,jasmine. All the blocks have common fields. Now i want to display all the contents of the view in my custom module.  When I tried the below code, I can access only the first block (ie)Rose. How can i get all the values of a view in my custom module?

```
$view = views_get_view(myblock_block');     
$view->set_display('Rose'); // page_1 or block_1 ... block_n, ...page_n
$view->set_items_per_page(0);
$view->execute();
$result = $view->result;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've always used [views_embed_view](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_embed_view/7) to do this. The first parameter is the machine name of your view, the second is the display id. Example:

```
$view_rose_output = views_embed_view('myblock_block', 'rose');
$view_lily_output = views_embed_view('myblock_block', 'lily').
```

If your view takes any arguments you can pass that in to the views_embed_view after the first two arguments.

Note that views_embed_view returns the rendered html of the view. If this is what you want, great! Otherwise, I've used the views_post_render hook to alter the output. The function header looks like this:

HOOK_views_post_render(&$view, &$output, &$cache)

where $output is the rendered html, and $view gives you the view object.

Comment: I really messed up with tww things.. about finding the display id and displaying as a object.. really great help for me. what should be the value of $view??  view name??

Comment: when using the views_post_render hook, the value for $view if the $view object after the views query is called. If you have devel installed, you can use kpr($view) in the hook to see what the $view object looks like Without devel, try print_r($view).